# Cholesky decomposition of matrix product, $A=BB^T$, where $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$

Tags: matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

Assume $A=BB^T$, where $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and therefore $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. The product $A$ is always symmetric positive definite. I want to find the Cholesky factor $A=LL^T$, where $L\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and it is lower triangular.

Is there a way to relate $B$ to $L$ without computing $A$ first?

Edit: Same question, but let now $A=(C\cdot B)B^T$, where $C \cdot B$ is the elementwise multiplication of C and B and $C=[C_1, C_2,...,C_m]$ is a collection of column vectors. Each column vector is a constant, $C_i = c_i I$ where $c_i$ is a scalar and $I\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$.

Comment: *"The product A is always symmetric positive definite"* No. It's always symmetric positive semidefinite. But unless $B$ has rank $\ge n$, it's singular (and if $m<n$ its rank is obviously $<n$).

Comment: True. However, in my specific case I know that $A$ is actually positive definite

Comment: The computation of $A$ from $B$ and/or $B$ and $C$ is straightforward, and the [Cholesky algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky%E2%80%93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky%E2%80%93Crout_algorithms) as well. Why do you want to make your life harder?

Comment: To avoid having an ill-conditioned $A$ matrix. I am only interested in the Cholesky factor of $A$ and not $A$ itself. Since I already know $A=(C \cdot B)B^T$, I thought there should be a way to get $L$ directly from $C$ and $B$.

Comment: This question is a duplicate and already has an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092558/computation-of-cholesky-decomposition-of-gram-matrix-from-its-components

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks!