# Square Root of Sample Covariance Matrix, the Component-Wise Formulation of

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, statistics, covariance

Let $X \in \mathbf R^{n \times p}, n<p$ be a given matrix.  Let us form the square matrix $M \in \mathbf R^{n \times n}$ such that $MM^T = XX^T.$  (This is done by writing down the diagonalisation $XX^T = A^T D A$, taking  $\sqrt D$ as the entry-wise square root of $D$, and then defining $M:= A^T \sqrt D$.)  Is it possible to describe the function $f$ such that

$$M_{i,j} = f(X_i,X_j)?$$

Thanks!

Comment: Somewhat related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589857/how-to-perform-low-rank-cholesky-like-factorization-and-what-is-it-called. And you don't need to diagonalize.